# how to automatic input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="tes.php">
<button type="button" id="setValueButton">xSmall</button>
<input data-max="5000" name="name[1]" type="text">
<button type="button" id="setValueButton">xSmall</button>
<input data-max="4000" name="name[2]" type="text">
<button type="button" id="setValueButton">xSmall</button>
<input data-max="1000" name="name[3]" type="text">
</form>
```

1. How to automatically input a value into the input if I click the button xSmall
2. If the user inputs a value greater than the data-max have the value set to data-max.

Comment: 1. Input *what* into the value? 2. What?

Comment: change the buttons to input type submit

Comment: 1. if me click button xSmall value data-max="xxx" show in input

Comment: 2. if the user change value input is greater than the data-max will be automatically changed to the value of max.

Answer (score 1):

First, each element has to have a unique ID:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="tes.php">
    <button type="button" id="setValueButton1">xSmall</button>
    <input data-max="5000" name="name[1]" type="text">
    <button type="button" id="setValueButton2">xSmall</button>
    <input data-max="4000" name="name[2]" type="text">
    <button type="button" id="setValueButton3">xSmall</button>
    <input data-max="1000" name="name[3]" type="text">
</form>
```

Then you need to use javascript (example in jQuery)

```
$('#setValueButton1').on('click', function () {
    $('input[name="name[1]"]').val('text string');
});
```

This example will enter a text string into the first box when you click the first button.

to detect a change to the input, use something like this:

```
$('#setValueButton1').on('change', function () {
    if ('#setValueButton1').val() > '5000' {
        // set it as above
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hmhf9mxf/